# Laravel 5 - Getting all records from a collection within a pivot

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

Ok,so I am setting up a relationship between my users and roles table, everything went fine until I tried to get every record. For example, If I just go with:

```
User::with('roles')->findOrFail(1);
```

Then all good, it returns the user and in that instance the 2 roles assigned.
However what I can't wrap my head around us this:

Say I want to get all the users and all their roles so I can display them out in a table for example, how would I do that? I just can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: I think you need to show some work of what you're trying that is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use findOrFail by itself without chaining another method `User::findOrFail(1)`, it will return a collection, but once you begin adding other conditions you must call either `->get()` for a collection of users, `->first` or `->last()` for a single user object or if you do something with  `->lists()` you will get an array. Otherwise you will get the builder class, here's an example of a {{ dd(User::where('id', 1)) }}

```
Builder {#1097 ▼
  #query: Builder {#1096 ▶}
  #model: User {#409 ▶}
  #eagerLoad: array:1 [▶]
  #macros: array:4 [▶]
  #onDelete: Closure {#1102 ▶}
  #passthru: array:12 [▶]
}
```

The Builder class is like a prepared statement which was never executed. When call to `dd()` you should see the something similar to the following.

This will give you a collection {{ dd(\App\User::where('id', 1)->get()) }}

```
Collection {#1105 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => User {#1108 ▼
      #cardUpFront: false
      #dates: array:3 [▶]
      #table: "users"
      #fillable: array:2 [▶]
      #hidden: array:2 [▶]
      #connection: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #perPage: 15
      +incrementing: true
      +timestamps: true
      #attributes: array:17 [▶]
      #original: array:17 [▶]
      #relations: []
      #visible: []
      #appends: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #casts: []
      #touches: []
      #observables: []
      #with: []
      #morphClass: null
      +exists: true
      #forceDeleting: false
    }
  ]
}
```

or to get a single object with {{ dd(\App\User::where('id', 1)->first()) }}

```
User {#1108 ▼
  #cardUpFront: false
  #dates: array:3 [▶]
  #table: "users"
  #fillable: array:2 [▶]
  #hidden: array:2 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: array:17 [▶]
  #original: array:17 [▶]
  #relations: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  #morphClass: null
  +exists: true
  #forceDeleting: false
}
```

and finally an array with {{ dd(\App\User::where('id', 1)->lists('email','id')) }}

```
array:1 [▼
  1 => "godfrey17@example.net"
]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I feel like an idiot, as soon as I went back to the laravel docs After reading this I seen the answer right away, no idea why I missed that, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to use get and that's all you should do.

Controller:

```
$users = User::with('roles')->get();
```

In your view file you should use another foreach if a user can have many roles:

View:

```
@foreach ($user as $user)

    <h1>{{ $user->name }}</h1>

    @foreach ($user->roles as $role)

        <h2>{{ $role->id }}</h2>

    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

Detailed info about [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading) is on [eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent) documentation.

Comment: Thank you too, the loop will do exactly what I require.